# the geo coder to fetch more requests

Tags: ruby, geocoding

I am working with geocoder gem and like to process more number of requests from an IP. By default Google API provides only 2500 requests per day.
Please share your thoughts on how I can do more requests than the limit?

Comment: I could think of one, not the best idea but you can ... pay google for the gmaps for business and get 100,000 requests!

Comment: you can't unless you pay for it and looking to increase requests from a single ip.

Answer (score 0):

As stated before: Using only Google API the only way around the limitation is to pay for it. Or in a more shady way make the requests form more than one IP/API-Key which i would not recommend.

But to stay on the save side i would suggest mixing the services up since there a few more Geocoding APIs out there - for free.

With the right gem mixing them is also not a big issue:

http://www.rubygeocoder.com/

Supports a couple of them with a nice interface. You would pretty much only have to add some rate-limiting counters making sure you stay within the limits of each provider.

Or go the heavy way of implementing your own geocoding. With for example your own running Openstreetmaps database. The Database can be downloaded here: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm#Worldwide_data

Which is the best way depends on what your actual requirements are and what ressources you have available.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestion..!